# Populating a TreeView from a database model in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, razor, treeview, razor-pages, kendo-treeview

I have a Razor pages project that is trying to populate a Kendo TreeView (or any other TreeView) from a Database created with a Data Model.

These are the relevant fields of the model:

```
namespace FliveRetry.Models
{
    public class Org
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string OrgName { get; set; }
        public int? ParentID { get; set; }
        public bool? HasChildren { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the view call:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownTree()
    .Name("selectedOrgs")
    .DataTextField("Org")
    .DataValueField("OrgID")
    .Checkboxes(true)
    .DataSource(d => d
        .Read(read =>
            read.Url("/Apps/Edit?handler=Read")
        )
    )
)
```

Hardcoding the values into a list like this below in OnGetRead works fine:

```
public IActionResult OnGetRead(int? id)
    {       
        var data = new List<Org>()
        {
            new Org() { ID = 1, ParentID = null, HasChildren = true, OrgName = "Org1" },
            new Org() { ID = 2, ParentID = null, HasChildren = false, OrgName = "Org2" },
            new Org() { ID = 3, ParentID = 1, HasChildren = true, OrgName = "Org3" },
            new Org() { ID = 4, ParentID = 3, HasChildren = false, OrgName = "Org4" }
        };

        var result = data.Where(x => id.HasValue ? x.ParentID == id : x.ParentID == null)
            .Select(item => new {
                id = item.ID,
                Org = item.OrgName,
                hasChildren = item.HasChildren
            });
            return new JsonResult(result);
        }
    }
```

[Hard Coded Values Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuFVf.png)

I am trying to Loop through the Org collection to populate the treeview with the Orgs from the Database.

Putting the for loop inside the List declaration creates errors everywhere, OnGetRead itself says not all code paths return a value:

```
public IActionResult OnGetRead(int? id)
        {
            var blnChildren = false;
            var data = new List<Org>()
            {       
                foreach (var item in _context.Org)
                {
                    blnChildren = false;
                    if (item.ParentID.Equals(null))
                        {
                        blnChildren = true;
                        }
                    new Org() { ID = item.ID, ParentID = item.ParentID, HasChildren = blnChildren, OrgName = item.OrgName };
                }       
            };

            var result = data.Where(x => id.HasValue ? x.ParentID == id : x.ParentID == null)
                .Select(item => new {
                    id = item.ID,

                    Org = item.OrgName,
                    hasChildren = item.HasChildren
                });

            return new JsonResult(result);
        }
```

If I put the for loop outside the List Declaration, the loop populates correctly but the result is empty, I'm guessing because the item declaration is outside the list?

```
public IActionResult OnGetRead(int? id)
        {
            var blnChildren = false;
            var data = new List<Org>()
            {       

            };
            foreach (var item in _context.Org)
            {
                blnChildren = false;
                if (item.ParentID.Equals(null))
                    {
                    blnChildren = true;
                    }
                new Org() { ID = item.ID, ParentID = item.ParentID, HasChildren = blnChildren, OrgName = item.OrgName };
            }

            var result = data.Where(x => id.HasValue ? x.ParentID == id : x.ParentID == null)
                .Select(item => new {
                    id = item.ID,
                    Org = item.OrgName,
                    hasChildren = item.HasChildren
                });

            return new JsonResult(result);
        }
```

Not sure if my problem is C# related or model related but any help would be appreciated.

Any other working example of a self referencing treeview working from a database model in a razor project rather than an MVC project would also help if I'm on the wrong track.

I have another example of the same issue using Kendo.Mvc.UI.TreeViewItemModel data that I can't get to work outside of hard coding either, I just need any version that works really.

Thanks heaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of stuff that you need to correct.

1. In forach loop you go trough each Org table item in DB creating query to Database each time. Thats a waste of time and resources. You should first query all the items you need from DB and then process them. If you need all the table entries you could just materialize them.

```
    var orgs = _context.Org.ToArray();
    foreach(var item in orgs)
    {
       //code here
```

2. You didn't add items into your data list inside foreach loop. You can do it like so

```
    var tmpOrg = new Org() { code code code} ;
    data.Add(tmpOrg);
```

3. **This whole thing can be simplified into one expression.** You don't need to materialize the whole table and you don't need that foreach loop. You can change the result expression to use _context.Org intead of data. In the Select clause on hasChildren you can just change this line

```
    hasChildren = item.ParentID == null ? true : false;
```

**EDIT**

What you should be left with is

```
public IActionResult OnGetRead(int? id)
{       
    var result = _context.Org.Where(x => id.HasValue ? x.ParentID == id : x.ParentID == null)
                             .Select(item => new 
                              {
                                  OrgID = item.ID,
                                  Org = item.OrgName,
                                  HasChildren = item.ParentID == null ? true : false
                              });

    return new JsonResult(result);       
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Arthur, that sounds brilliant.
Unfortunately my skills aren't great just yet, I can't see quite how to put it together.
This below is what I put together, but it isn't right:
`
var orgs = _context.Org.ToArray();
   var data = new List<Org>()
   {    
   };
   var tmpOrg = new Org()
   {
    data.Add(tmpOrg);
   };   
   var result = data.Where(x => id.HasValue ? x.ParentID == id : x.ParentID == null)
    .Select(item => new {
     id = item.ID,
     Org = item.OrgName,
     hasChildren = item.ParentID == null ? true : false
    });
   return new JsonResult(result);
`

Comment: Obviously haven't worked out how to reply correctly to comments either :(

Comment: @tonyRyan You're almost there. Remove the first line where you materialize Org table. Remove second line (btw if you don't initialize list with values than you can omit the curly braces). You don't need third line with tmpOrg. In Fourth line replace 'data' with '_context.Org' and remove Where(...) clause. And that's all :)

Comment: Thanks @Arthur. Unfortunately, I am lost. I appreciate your help and I'm happy to commend, tick, share or pay you for some help in giving me the actual answer. I just need one working example to replicate.
This is what I now have, can you please fix it? Telerik can't seem to give me anything but hard coded solutions. 
Thanks mate.
`
public IActionResult OnGetRead(int? id)
   {  
   
   };
   var result = _context.Org.Select(item => new { id = item.ID, Org = item.OrgName, hasChildren = item.ParentID == null ? true : false }); 
  
   return new JsonResult(result);
  }
`

Comment: @TonyRyan I have edited the answer and added solution to it. I have also changed property names inside Select clause because I can see that in Kendo you are binding dataTextFiled to Org filed which I assume is organization name. I also changed id into OrgID because you are also binding to it in Kendo. Please don't forget to accept the answer :).

Comment: @TonyRyan I corrected the query. I realized that id is a method input parameter. Now Where clause makes sense. Sorry for that.

Comment: Thanks @Arthur. That is working, but it is just throwing the parents to the control, not the children, so only ParentID of null is showing. I also had to take the semi colon off the HasChildren line to get rid of errors about not all code returning values. Any ideas? No problem with accepting the answer, really appreciate your efforts.

Comment: @TonyRyan probably it's because you are sending NULL as input parameter (id). Try to send some integer (e.g. 1). If it's always NULL that you get then check your JavaScript code if it's populating Json data properly.

Comment: yeah you are right, id is null. I don't have any javascript running, would the javascript be in the .cshtml page?

Comment: @TonyRyan Yes it can be either code in cshtml file or just referenced in that file like that '<script src="yourScript.js"></script>' but most likely it's Kendo that's making the request. I'm not familiar with that framework but from this little code snippet that you provided in the question I can tell that You are using Kendo extension for MVC [Kendo for .Net](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/html-helper-basics-of-kendo-ui-for-asp-net-mvc-beta). You will have investigate that by yourself. That's all I can do for you. Please don't forget to accept the answer. Thanks :).